# Laravel 5.2 Returning View from a controller

Tags: controller, routes, laravel-5

I have a view defined in a subdirectory "admin" which is an edit form. When submitted this is handed to a controller with the following code:

```
class ThisSiteController extends Controller
{
    public function updateSite(Request $request)
    {
        $thissite = DB::table('this_site')->where('id',1)->get();
        $thissite->headline = $request->headline;
        $thissite->save();  
        return view('admin.editfront')->with('site', $thissite);
    };
}
```

It is updating the one headline OK but I always get

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Although the route that calls the edit is (and works fine):

```
Route::get('/admin/editfront', function() {
    $thissite = DB::table('this_site')->where('id',1)->get();
    return view('admin.editfront')->with('site', $thissite);
});
```

Comment: Yes. The db is updated OK. It is the line calling the view that is giving the error.

Comment: No - I just call the controller method from the form.

Comment: @Jim when do you get this error ? After submitting the form or before it ?

Comment: return view like this ... return view('admin.editfront' , ['site' => $thissite]);

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting a form, make sure the route is using post.

```
Route::post('/admin/editfront', 'ThisSiteController@updateSite');
```

If that isnt the issue can you show your form code, and the route for the update?

EDIT

```
class ThisSiteController extends Controller
{
    public function updateSite(Request $request)
    {
        DB::table('this_site')
            ->where('id',1)
            ->update(['headline' => $request->input('headline')]);
        $thissite = DB::table('this_site')->where('id',1)->first();
        return view('admin.editfront')->with('site', $site);
    };
}
```

Comment: I've changed the form to <form id="form1" method="post" action="/admin/editfront"> but I am still getting an error

Comment: Sorry typo. Fiorm  is now form id="form1" method="post" action="{{/admin/editf‌​ront}}"> I am now getting "ErrorException in ThisSiteController.php line 16: Trying to get property of non-object" when the referring to   $thissite->headline = $request->headline;.

Comment: thats because `get()` returns an array of results. Use `find(1)` or `$thissite[0]->headline`

Comment: Did that. Now I have FatalErrorException in ThisSiteController.php line 18: Call to a member function save() on array

Comment: again, `$thissite` is an array, `$thissite[0]->save()` if you want to save that model but its better to use `first()` or `find()` methods

Comment: I changes things to $thissite = DB::table('this_site')->first();
        $thissite->headline = $request->headline;

        $thissite->save(); but now I get Call to undefined method stdClass::save()

Comment: Do you have a model for `this_site` table?

Comment: No. Well a blank one.

Comment: I edited my answer, it should now do what you want. Without a working model this is probably the best you can get.

Comment: The update line gives Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: I updated it, try again. If it doesnt work can you insert the whole error message?

Comment: Still error - NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

    in RouteCollection.php line 161
    at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821
    at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246

Comment: You must've changed something else. This means some route is not found.

Comment: No. The route is there. This is the original error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you move the edit action to controller method as well and the following changes to updateSite method shall fix the update issue. It would have been much simpler if you have used the Models.

```
class ThisSiteController extends Controller{

  public function updateSite(Request $request){
    $thissite = DB::table('this_site')->where('id',1)->update(['headline' => $request->get('headline')]);

    return view('admin.editfront',['site' => $thissite]);
  }

  public function editSite(){
    $thissite = DB::table('this_site')->where('id',1)->first();
    return view('admin.editfront',['site' => $thissite]);
  }
}
```

Also do route editfront route to `ThisSiteController@editSite` method.

for the form action you can have `action="{{ action('ThisSiteController@editSite') }}"`

Answer (score 0):

You are using get request in route, this might be causing a problem.

If you are using POST method in form, change your route to:

```
Route::post('/admin/editfront',ThisSiteController@updateSite});
```

It would be very useful if you can show the whole error message or route file.